# Handling of Nested Maps

Tags: scala, databricks

I have a Map which has a key containing another Map.
i.e -

```
val myDetailsMap = Map("name" -> "abc",
                       "class" -> "10",
                       "section" -> "A",
                       "marksPerSubjectId" -> Map(101 -> "Physics= '70' AND Chemistry='80'",
                                                  102 -> "History= '60' AND Civics = '67'"),
                       "status" -> "pass")
```

Now, I want to iterate through the `marksPerSubjectId` key containing another MAP using `foreach`. How should I proceed ?

On Databricks -
[image]

Comment: This is poorly very typed. You basically have a `Map[String, Any]` there. Why modeling things this way?

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok, The issue is I am taking the Inputs from Databricks Widgets. To have a a clean Input, I was storing everything in a Map, I am updating it with the exact scenario, maybe you can suggest me a better way to get the data from databricks widgets

Answer (score 0):

What about using pattern matching?

in Scala 2.13:

```
myDetailsMap.foreachEntry{ (k, v) =>
  v match {
    case map: Map[_, _] => map.foreachEntry{ (k, v) => println(v)}
    case other => println(other)
  }
}
```

in Scala 2.11:

```
myDetailsMap.foreach{ case (k, v) =>
  v match {
    case map: Map[_, _] => map.foreach{ case (k, v) => println(v)}
    case other => println(other)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @kanbangoly, But this is giving me this error - `command-14666149:8: error: value foreachEntry is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Object]
myDetailsMap.foreachEntry{ (k, v) =>`

Comment: What version of Scala do you have? Maybe the `foreachEntry` only works in 2.13>= .
If you have older version, can you try `foreach` instead of `foreachEntry`?

Comment: I am on 2.11. Cant upgrade to a higher version, Its a mandate to be on 2.11.

Comment: Is it working with changing both `foreachEntry` to `foreach` ?

Comment: `foreach` works. New error - `command-14666149:8: error: missing parameter type
Note: The expected type requires a one-argument function accepting a 2-Tuple.
      Consider a pattern matching anonymous function, `{ case (k, v) =>  ... }`
myDetailsMap.foreach{ (k, v)`

Comment: I updated the my answer with a solution with 2.11, can you check that one? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much @kanbagoly. It works, Let me Check if i can use it or not . Accordingly , I will update here. Thanks again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218448/discussion-between-golokesh-patra-and-kanbagoly).